# Xpath/XSLT automatically transform URL into XSLFO-link

Tags: xml, xpath, xsl-fo

I have an an xml file with a footer with a couple of lines of text. The (usually) last String of that footer is a URL `(https://....`). Is there a way to make XPath or XSL extract that URL from the footer-text and turn it into an fo:basic-link?

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Comment: Do you have an input XML example?

Comment: <footer>Blla bla bla bla text text tex. Text, more text. text and then the url h ttps://www.xxx.xxx.com</footer>

Comment: What versions of XPath/XSL are you able to use? As the string is only usually the last part of that footer, we need to deal with strings after it? Is it always an https url? Are there other URLs in the footer?

Comment: I'm able to use versions 1.0 of XSL and Xpath. The url is always https and there is only one url in each footer. There are no strings after the url, so it definitely is the last string of each footer.

Comment: In the question you have `(http://.... )` but in the comment above you say "the url is always https". Be careful with the details. Instead of adding important information in comments, please update the question.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I've just changed it.